# Sign in pop up - Encrypt username password values

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a Sign-In functionality implemented as a pop up. It appears in Landing page and Pop up is inside the markup of this page.
Landing page is not SSL enabled (Not https), but when the user tries to Sign In I want the passwords to be sent to the server via SSL.

What is the recommended approach to achive this?

Answer (score 6):

The mix between http and https is not a good idea. Troy Hunt (among others) wrote an article showing how wrong things can get: [5 ways to implement HTTPS in an insufficient manner (and leak sensitive data)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/04/5-ways-to-implement-https-in.html).

See also [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), which is a good thing.